# How do I connect AS3.0 to a variable in js?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I've got an AS3 code that I want to assign in JavaScript as a variable like so:

```
var Name = ;
```

If I want to set a simple stylesheet I would use:

```
var Name = { Name.width:500 }
```

etc.

How do I do that in AS3?
i want to do it like so

```
var As3 = action script code;
```

**i want to give a var to the actionscript so i can use it later**

Comment: Do you really mean what you said? :)

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, and I may have mis-interpreted it for my answer.  Please add details about what you're trying to do, and how and why you're trying to do it.

Answer (score 2):

A SWF on a webpage can interoperate (call functions, set variables, etc) with JavaScript using ActionScript's [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

For example:

```
ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "Hello JavaScript world!");
```

Apparently calling eval only works in some browsers, but you can proxy the eval [as noted in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837959/externalinterface-call-using-actionscript-eval-only-works-in-firefox-not-chrom).

```
ExternalInterface.call("eval", "window.foo = 'bar'");
```

Of course, your CSS example is very malformed...  You might could:

```
ExternalInterface.call("eval", "document.getElementById('myDiv').style.width='50px'");
```

Google for more examples of using ExternalInterface to set variables, call functions, setup callbakcs, etc.

Comment: Thanks but im kind of new to js so if you can explain it, it would be helpful

Comment: All the explanation you could want: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html